# Data in RecyclerView does not change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm making a task that changes the `unit property` of the recycler view list in batches using a `toggle button`.

Since you are using `MVVM` pattern your logic will be executed in `Repository`.

Through debugging, it was confirmed that the unit of all items in the Repository List changes.

However, there is no change on the screen even if I put a value in _items.value of the ViewModel.

I'm not sure where the problem is.

---

**WorkoutSetInfo**

```
data class WorkoutSetInfo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val set: Int,
    var weight: String = "0",
    var reps: String = "0",
    var unit: WorkoutUnit = WorkoutUnit.kg,
    val parentWorkoutId: Long = 0
)
```

**Repository**

```
class WriteDetailRepository(val dao: WorkoutDao) {
    private var setInfoList = arrayListOf(WorkoutSetInfo(set = 1)) // fixed set 1
    private var updatedList = listOf<WorkoutSetInfo>()
                get() = setInfoList.toList()

    fun changeUnit(unit: WorkoutUnit) {
        updatedList = setInfoList.map { setInfo ->
            setInfo.copy(unit = unit)
        }
    }

    fun add() {
        val item = WorkoutSetInfo(set = setInfoList.size + 1)
        setInfoList.add(item)
        updatedList = setInfoList.toList()
    }
    
    fun getList() : List<WorkoutSetInfo> = updatedList
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class WriteDetailViewModel(
    private val repository: WriteDetailRepository
    ): ViewModel() {

    private var _items: MutableStateFlow<List<WorkoutSetInfo>> = MutableStateFlow(repository.getList())
    val items = _items.asStateFlow()

    fun changeUnit(unit: WorkoutUnit) {
        repository.changeUnit(unit)
        _items.value = repository.getList()
    }

    fun addSet() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.add()
            _items.value = repository.getList() // here
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class WriteDetailFragment :  Fragment() {
    
    ...
    private val viewModel: WriteDetailViewModel by viewModels {
        WriteDetailViewModelFactory(
            (requireActivity().application as WorkoutApplication).writeDetailRepo
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentWriteDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.apply {
            ...
            
            addSet.setOnClickListener {
                viewModel.addSet()
            }

          
            unitToggle.addOnButtonCheckedListener { _, checkedId, isChecked ->
                if(isChecked) {
                    when(checkedId) {
                        R.id.kg -> viewModel.changeUnit(WorkoutUnit.kg)
                        R.id.lb -> viewModel.changeUnit(WorkoutUnit.lbs)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.items.collect { list -> // list value does not change
                    adapter.submitList(list)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try this out `_items.value.copy(repository.getList())` in `changeUnit()`?

Comment: this code  occured Syntax Error..